# Recipe for homemade Sugru (Oogoo) that permanently adheres to objects

Tags: adhesive, silicone

https://www.instructables.com/id/Homemade-Sugru-IMPROVED/ has a reply of:

> Let's see... 1.5 units (by volume) of cornstarch mixed with 2 units of silicone. Add some kind of paint for color. OR maybe 3 units of silicone mixed with 1 unit of cornstarch. Experiment with variable ratios. Read [the Wikipedia article on Sugru](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sugru), learning they mix Silicone, talc and other ingredients... don't inhale or light cigarettes while experimenting, right?

And there are a metric ton of Youtube videos like [this one](https://youtu.be/_nXy1j5b6q0) that go into detail about how to mix it.  But on that video you will see the application is for making molds, and he used various materials on the yet-to-be-solidified mixture, and after drying, pulled the objects off of it to show little to no adhesion *onto those objects he is molding upon*. For my purposes, I want initial moldability for a few minutes, but then "stickability" comparable for the original Sugru. Basically, I actually do want the resulting [Oogoo](https://www.instructables.com/id/How-To-Make-Your-Own-Sugru-Substitute/) to stick permanently to those objects I apply it to.

To accomplish this, is this simply a matter of experimenting with the ratios of silicone rubber and corn-starch, or do I also need to add in those other ingredients such as talc etc to get the same/similar level of adhesion properties?

Another way to say this: Is there a particular reason the Sugru makers chose talc over corn-starch, or is it simply a choice based upon their production costs?  I speculate that DIY'ers might choose corn-starch over talc for reasons having little to do with adhesion properties (use with the resulting product with food preparation?).

Comment: This doesn't seem like the venue for this question.

Comment: Interesting question, but it isn't a Home Improvement Question.

Comment: cornstarch can mold and feed bacteria, and rot away; leaving tiny gaps that harbor germs. It sounds more like you need an epoxy putty; those pliability agents will categorically prevent silicone adhesion.

Comment: I agree that this forum isn't ideal. Perhaps the art and crafts or chemistry stock exchanges would be better choices.  However, this is related to the do-it-yourself movement, hence the diy part of diy.stackechange.com.

Comment: @dandavis interesting observation. If my intent was to prevent adhesion, then epoxy putty does seem like something to investigate. However I'm wanting to increase adhesion.

Comment: @dandavis I suspect your [comment](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/177241/recipe-for-homemade-sugru-oogoo-that-permanently-adheres-to-objects?noredirect=1#comment305313_177241) is a viable answer. Please post it and I'll mark it as "the" answer for now, and other people can add their own over time.